# Whiteboard with Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, whiteboard

Community,
I have Raspberry Pi 3 model B and in this Raspberry installed Raspbian. So I'm trying to connect whiteboard to Raspbian, but I can't connect. I think the problem is related with drivers. Can someone tell me is any whiteboard driver exist for Raspbian? If no can we somehow convert windows driver to Raspbian? 
If my question wrongs sorry. I'm a new programmer for devices

Comment: Its linux question, so there are lot of type of whiteboard, could you precise?